# Add legend to the curve from \draw

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am a new user to [PGFPlots](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/) so I have the following question: I draw a ellipse in TikZ and I want to add a legend for it. However, I found the `\addlegendentry` is only for `\addplot`. Then, how can I add a legend for my curve?

```
\tikzsetnextfilename{1a}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
 xlabel = $\dfrac{M}{M_{bend}}$,
 ylabel = $\dfrac{P}{P_{burst}}$,
  xmin=0,xmax=1.2,
  ymin=0,ymax=1.2,
 ymajorgrids=true,
 xmajorgrids=true,
 grid style=dashed,
 label style={font=\tiny},
 tick label style={font=\tiny},
 legend style={font=\small},
 legend cell align=left,
 legend pos=north east
  ]
 \addplot+[color=red,
 line width=0.3mm] 
 (axis cs:0,0)
   ellipse [
  x radius=0.950052, y radius=0.945021];
\addlegendentry{Analytical results}
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I read about the customized legend from  [Customize legend position in PGFplots axis environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134084/customize-legend-position-in-pgfplots-axis-environment), but I have no idea about how to put this in an axis environment.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Answer (score 10):

You can use `\addlegendimage` to add a legend for a `\draw` command. The argument to `\addlegendimage` is just the same style parameters used in the `draw`, e.g. `red,line width=0.3mm`. The problem with using `\draw` like this is however that the scale is wrong, as it doesn't use the coordinate system of the `axis`.

Another option here is to plot the ellipse with `addplot`, which gives the correct size.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,amsmath}

\begin{document}  
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
 xlabel = $\dfrac{M}{M_{\mathrm{bend}}}$,
 ylabel = $\dfrac{P}{P_{\mathrm{burst}}}$,
  xmin=0,xmax=1.2,
  ymin=0,ymax=1.2,
 ymajorgrids=true,
 xmajorgrids=true,
 grid style=dashed,
 label style={font=\tiny},
 tick label style={font=\tiny},
 legend style={font=\small},
 legend cell align=left,
 legend pos=north east
  ]

\draw[color=red,
 line width=0.3mm] 
 (axis cs:0.6,0.6) % moved to middle of plot to make it more visible
   ellipse [
  x radius=0.950052, y radius=0.945021];

\addlegendimage{line width=0.3mm,color=red}
\addlegendentry{Analytical results}

\addplot [variable=\t,samples=200,domain=0:360] ({0.950052*cos(t)},{0.945021*sin(t)});
\addlegendentry{Parametric analytic}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. The reason I use \draw is I can't find a good way to plot ellipse by \addplot. Then, problem solved!