# Unknown error using legend entries

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

I'm having trouble with my tikzpicture. I have the following code:

```latex
          \begin{center}
                    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 1]
                    \begin{axis}[
                          axis x line=center,
                          axis y line=center,
                          legend entries={Creciente, Estrictamente Creciente},
                          legend pos=north,
                          xtick={-5,-4,...,5},
                          ytick={-5,-4,...,5},
                          xlabel={$x$},
                          ylabel={$y$},
                          xlabel style={below right},
                          ylabel style={above left},
                          xmin=-5.5,
                          xmax=5.5,
                          ymin=-5.5,
                          ymax=5.5]
                        \addlegendimage{no markers,magenta}
                        \addlegendimage{no markers,blue}
                        
                        \addplot [
                            domain=-5:1, 
                            samples=100, 
                            color=magenta]
                            {x/2};
                        \addplot [
                            domain=1:2, 
                            samples=100, 
                            color=magenta]
                            {0.5};
                        \addplot [
                            domain=2:5, 
                            samples=100, 
                            color=magenta]
                            {(x/2)-0.5};
                        \addplot [
                            domain=-5:5, 
                            samples=100, 
                            color=blue]
                            {(x/2)+0.5};
                    \end{axis}
                    
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{center}
```

The image looks ok but an error appears in the log: *Package pgfkeys Error: Choice 'center' unknown in choice key '/pgfplots/legend pos'. I am going to ignore this key.* I think that the problem are the legend entries but I can't figure out the error.

Comment: please provide a test file that produces the error, not just a fragment

Comment: The problem really is that `north` is not a known value for `legend pos`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you face is that `north` is not a valid value for `legend pos`. According to the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf) (section 4.9. on "Axis Descriptions") you can only use `south west`, `south east`, `north west`, `north east` or `outer north east`.

However, the manual also states that using this sytax essentially is a shorthand for  setting the options `at` and `anchor`. The default value for `at` according to the manual is `(0.98,0.98)` which denotes `north east`. The values for `at` describe the position on the x and y axes respectively, so that 0 denotes the lower left and 1 the upper right corner of the plot.

So, you can place the legend at the `north` anchor of the plot using `legend style={at={(0.5,0.98)}, anchor=north}`. (Note that `anchor=north` here describes the anchor of the legend, not the anchor of the plot.)

Of course, placing the legend there would have it covering the y axis.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 1]
    \begin{axis}[
          axis x line=center,
          axis y line=center,
          legend entries={Creciente, Estrictamente Creciente},
          legend style={at={(0.5,0.98)}, anchor=north},
          xtick={-5,-4,...,5},
          ytick={-5,-4,...,5},
          xlabel={$x$},
          ylabel={$y$},
          xlabel style={below right},
          ylabel style={above left},
          xmin=-5.5,
          xmax=5.5,
          ymin=-5.5,
          ymax=5.5]
        \addlegendimage{no markers,magenta}
        \addlegendimage{no markers,blue}
        
        \addplot [
            domain=-5:1, 
            samples=100, 
            color=magenta]
            {x/2};
        \addplot [
            domain=1:2, 
            samples=100, 
            color=magenta]
            {0.5};
        \addplot [
            domain=2:5, 
            samples=100, 
            color=magenta]
            {(x/2)-0.5};
        \addplot [
            domain=-5:5, 
            samples=100, 
            color=blue]
            {(x/2)+0.5};
    \end{axis}
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Also see this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134084/47927